# Compile non-mpi libraries with mpicc

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

I want to compile mpi with my own libraries. And I'm not sure if the options that work on gcc such as -I/ -L/ are available for mpicc.

I'm trying to compile with the following options but I get the following error.

```
mpicc -I$(CURRENT_DIR)/util -I$(CURRENT_DIR) -L$(CURRENT_DIR)/util -o server server.c
```

```
mpicc -I./util -I. -L./util -o server server.c
/tmp/ccA5be6Z.o: En la función `main':
server.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `list_create'
server.c:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `list_add'
server.c:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `list_count'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Those are my server.c includes

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <list.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
```

And this is my pwd/util folder

```
$ ls
list.c list.h list.o
...
```

Comment: `list.o` is not a library; it is an object.

Comment: You're not including any additional libraries *or* objects in your link.  The `-L` option just adds a directory in which to look for libraries specified by an `-l` option.  There is no option that automatically checks or links libraries or objects that are not designated in the compile / link command.

Comment: you could just add the `list.c` at the end of your command line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mpicc (and the other MPI build commands) are only wrappers on top of your compilers. So if you are using gcc, all the gcc options and directives are available.

Concerning OpenMPI, you can exhibit the compiler and the options used by using the --showme option. You can see the details in the OpenMPI FAQ (https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#wrapper-showme-with-no-file). Similar options are available in MPICH (https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2.x/www1/mpicc.html)

Your issue here is not related to MPI. You are just missing adding some objects (probably list.o) in the linking step. You should consider creating a Makefile to ease the build process.